# Audio potentiometer output shorted to ground

Tags: circuit-design, diagram

I'm working on a schematic where it seems the second pin of a trimmer potentiometer (the output pin) is shorted with the ground pin.  This is then fed into an audio output. Is this normal or am I understanding something wrong? Shouldn't the potetiometer's third pin actually go to ground?

Here's a photo of this component:

[image: RV1 Image]

[The schematic is from here.](http://www.judoles.nl/Projecten/14channelSA/Fullschematic.pdf)

Comment: That makes it a variable resistance. The circuit is designed for that use.

Comment: A potentiometer doesn't have a "ground pin", nor does it have an "output pin". The functionality of each pin depends on how the component is used, and there is more than one way to use a potentiometer,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image]

> Shouldn't the pot's 3rd pin actually go to gnd?

Yes, one end of the 2 terminal pins goes to gnd when it works as a "voltage divider". Meantime, another end terminal is connected to the input signal. Thus the center terminal (wiper) voltage is adjusted by changing the wiper position along the two end terminals. That is visualized on your TV screen when you raise or lower the volume. The range (full-scale) is fixed amount, and the wiper position varies from the bottom(gnd) to the top(max input).

> The second pin of a trimmer pot (the output pin) is shorted with the
> ground pin. Is this normal ?

When a [OP-amp (Operational Amplifier)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier) is used, the input signal is amplified and presented to the ouput by the ratio of (R2 + RV1):R12. Thus the value of RV1 adjusts the "amplitude of the amplification" (gain) by the resistance across the two connection points. And, we need only one side of the resistor from the wiper position, ie. one terminal pin and the center pin. Thus, unneeded terminal pin can be either float, or tied to the center pin. When the wiper is tied to a terminal pin, the resistance on that terminal side is canceled (to zero ohm).

Answer (score 1):

This type of variable resistor has the structure shown in this photo.

[image]

https://www.circuitstoday.com/variable-resistor

By turning the knob, you add resistance to one resistor while reducing the resistance to the other. The total resistance between them stays the same. In the picture you showed, they just shorted the center terminal to one side so only the resistance of the other side is seen by the circuit.